# MDX Sort By Month

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I am trying to put together my first query for a `pentaho` CDE dashboard chart.

**Starting Query**

```
WITH 
  SET [~COLUMNS] AS 
    {[DimProgram.Name].[Name].MEMBERS} 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    {[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].MEMBERS} 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [~COLUMNS]
     ,{[Measures].[SubmissionCount]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

[image]

This query returns the data I want but needs to be tweaked a bit to be ready for actual use. I want to sort by date descending and limit to only the past 12 months.

I've read several webpages on sorting in MDX, but haven't been able to put together a query that will run. When the query doesn't run just an "Error" prompt.

**Ordering Attempt**

```
WITH 
  SET [~COLUMNS] AS 
    {[DimProgram.Name].[Name].MEMBERS} 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [~COLUMNS]
     ,{[Measures].[SubmissionCount]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].MEMBERS
     ,[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Member_Key
     ,DESC
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

Any tips on sorting or how to limit to the past X months would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a Date/Time dimension is ordered naturally in the cube design so there is no need to use `Order`. I don't need to with the cubes I use.

If it is in a strange order in the cube then you need to break (`B`) this hierarchical order by using `BASC` or `BDESC`:

```
WITH 
  SET [~COLUMNS] AS 
    {[DimProgram.Name].[Name].MEMBERS} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[orderMeas] AS 
    [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    Order
    (
      [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[orderMeas]
     ,BASC
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [~COLUMNS]
     ,{[Measures].[SubmissionCount]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

To get the most recent 12 months you can use the `Tail` function - better to use it against NonEmpty months:

```
WITH 
  SET [~COLUMNS] AS 
    {[DimProgram.Name].[Name].MEMBERS} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[orderMeas] AS 
    [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    Order
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[SubmissionCount]
      )
     ,[Measures].[orderMeas]
     ,BASC
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [~COLUMNS]
     ,{[Measures].[SubmissionCount]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Tail
    (
      [~ROWS]
     ,12
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

Hi Andrew - against `AdvWrks` I've got the following running without any errors. I needed to change `Member_Key` to `MemberValue`:

```
WITH 
  SET [~COLUMNS] AS 
    [Product].[Product Categories].[Product]
  MEMBER [Measures].[orderMeas] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  SET [~ROWS] AS 
    Order
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
     ,[Measures].[orderMeas]
     ,ASC
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [~COLUMNS]
     ,{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Tail
    (
      [~ROWS]
     ,12
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looking at the order query, reading the code itself makes sense, but when put in doesn't run. Is there a favorite tool you use for writing/testing these sort of queries? I imagine I should get back sort sort of at least semi-helpful error message to help see where I went wrong.

Comment: just `SSMS` should produce an error message? I use MDX Studio (it's free) to play with mdx. Let me create a prototype like your script against AdvWrks cube just to check the structure of my answer.

Comment: It does seem like most people are using analysis services & most of the tools are geared towards that.

Comment: @AndrewWalters this is the best tool, it is free, and was created by one of the founders of the mdx language: https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/mdx-studio/